# Importance of using the right "you"

Tags: ustedeo

I'm doing a "Survival Spanish for Librarians" course. I have a basic understanding of grammar level Spanish and some conversational skills, but I'm not very confident.

My problem with this course is it keeps using the informal second person form. Quieres, Puedes, Necesitas, etc. I feel like I should address adult patrons as "usted," not "tú".

Am I over thinking this or should I continue to try to adjust every phrase I'm learning appropriately? It's an online course so it marks me as wrong and I just have to use google/prior knowledge to judge the best answers for myself.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

This question might be marked as opinion based but still I'll give you *mine*

You are right. It is more polite to address adult patrons as "usted" however you are also right about overthinking it. I would guess that if one of your patrons that does not speak English arrives to your library and you greet them in Spanish they will feel very happy regardless of you using *usted* or *tu*.

During the course obviously you have to use *tu* to pass it but if the course is called "survival" and you are using *survival* Spanish to help your library patrons then whatever comes to mind first and is easier for you, would be just fine. As your spanish level progresses you will be using more proper grammar but in the meantime don't overthink it :)

Once I was talking to some person from the US and I told him "forgive me because my English is not very good". His answer was "if my Spanish was better than your English we should be speaking in Spanish." The same applies here.